# Dollar symbol should be around entities and values- Perl

Tags: perl

I have confusion with my code to remove dollars inside the digits (multi values) and to be inserted the dollar symbol around the values.

Sure I am little bit confused.

For e.g.: `10$x$10$x$10$x$10`  should be `$10x10x10x10$`  #might be 'n' numbered infinite.

My code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $tmp = do { local $/; $_ = <DATA>; };
my @allines = split /\n/, $tmp;
for(@allines)
{
    my $lines = $_;

    my ($pre,$matches,$posts) = "";

    $lines=~s/(\d+)(\$*)\\times\$(\d+)/$1$2\\times$3\$/g;

    print $lines;
}
```

Input:

````
__DATA__
where $Q=k-k^{\prime}$ is the scattering vector of length $4\pi \sin{\theta} /{\lambda}$ for a neutron of wavelength ${\lambda}$ scattered at an angle $2{\theta}$, and k and k' are X-ray absorption spectroscopy. Thus, RMC trials were performed for several samples assuming either A 10$\times$10$\times$10 supercell was first built, based on the unit cell model Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues.... Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues.... Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues.... obtained.


Required Output:

where $Q=k-k^{\prime}$ is the scattering vector of length $4\pi \sin{\theta} /{\lambda}$ for a neutron of wavelength ${\lambda}$ scattered at an angle $2{\theta}$, and k and k' are X-ray absorption spectroscopy. Thus, RMC trials were performed for several samples assuming either A $10\times10\times10$ supercell was first built, based on the unit cell model Sample paragraph testing $10\times10\times10$ text continues.... Sample paragraph testing $10\times10\times10\times10$ text continues.... Sample paragraph testing $10\times10\times10\times10\times10\times10$ text continues.... obtained.```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to blindly transform `10$x$10$x$10$x$10` into `$10x10x10x10$` without taking account anything about the surrounding text, then this should be enough.

```
$lines=~s/(\d+)\$/\$$1/g;
```

If your requirements are more complex than that, you need to update the question with the details.

**[UPDATE]**

Just looking again at the input and expected output, I see there is a complication -- some of the input looks like this `times$10$` with the expected output `times$10`. That means we have an optional leading `$` that needs to be taken into account.

To deal with that we can add `\$?` to the start of the regex to match the optional `$`, like this

```
$lines=~s/\$?(\d+)\$/\$$1/g;
```

Below is a rewrite of your code that also removes some of the unnecessary splitting

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>)
{
    s/\$?(\d+)\$/\$$1/g;

    print ;
}

__DATA__
Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues....
Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues....
Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues....
```

Output is

```
Sample paragraph testing $10\times$10\times$10 text continues....
Sample paragraph testing $10\times$10\times$10\times$10 text continues....
Sample paragraph testing $10\times$10\times$10\times$10\times$10\times$10 text continues....
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

Assuming the actual requirements are

1. change the first occurrence of, say, `123$` into `$123`
2. for last occurrence of `$123`, change to `123$`
3. for the intermediate digit-dollar sequences, remove the dollars.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>)
{
    # replace the first occurrence only
    s/\$?(\d+)\$/\$$1/;

    # remove $ from the all but the last digit-dollar
    # uses lookahead to prevent matching the last digit-dollar
    s/times\$?(\d+)\$?(?=\\t)/times$1/g;

    # rework the last occurrence of digit-dollar
    s/times\$(\d+)/times$1\$/;

    print ;
}


Input:

__DATA__
Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues....
Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues....
Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues....
```

output is

```
Sample paragraph testing $10\times10\times10$ text continues....
Sample paragraph testing $10\times10\times10\times10$ text continues....
Sample paragraph testing $10\times10\times10\times10\times10\times10$ text continues....
```

**UPDATE 3**

New requirement -- there can be multiple digit-dollar sequences in a single line.

This complicates the code a bit, but not much.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>)
{
    # walk the string looking for strings of the form "10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10"

    while (s/(.*?)((\$?\d+\$?\\times)+\$?\d+\$?)//)
    {
        # output any data that preceded the digit-dollar sequence
        print $1;

        my $block = $2;

        # Remove all dollars
        $block =~ s/\$+//g;

        # put back the initial dollar
        $block =~ s/^(\d+)/\$$1/;

        # and the terminating dollar
        $block =~ s/$/\$/;

        # output the modified digit-dollar sequence
        print $block;
    }

    # output trailing text
    print;

}


Input:

__DATA__
where $Q=k-k^{\prime}$ is the scattering vector of length $4\pi \sin{\theta} /{\lambda}$ for a neutron of wavelength ${\lambda}$ scattered at an angle $2{\theta}$, and k and k' are X-ray absorption spectroscopy. Thus, RMC trials were performed for several samples assuming either A 10$\times$10$\times$10 supercell was first built, based on the unit cell model Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues.... Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues.... Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues.... obtained.

Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues....
Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues....
Sample paragraph testing 10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10$\times$10 text continues....
```

output is

```
where $Q=k-k^{\prime}$ is the scattering vector of length $4\pi \sin{\theta} /{\lambda}$ for a neutron of wavelength ${\lambda}$ scattered at an angle $2{\theta}$, and k and k' are X-ray absorption spectroscopy. Thus, RMC trials were performed for several samples assuming either A $10\times10\times10$ supercell was first built, based on the unit cell model Sample paragraph testing $10\times10\times10$ text continues.... Sample paragraph testing $10\times10\times10\times10$ text continues.... Sample paragraph testing $10\times10\times10\times10\times10\times10$ text continues.... obtained.

Sample paragraph testing $10\times10\times10$ text continues....
Sample paragraph testing $10\times10\times10\times10$ text continues....
Sample paragraph testing $10\times10\times10\times10\times10\times10$ text continues....
```

Comment: I think that's still not what the OP wants. Seems like the requirement can be summarised as "remove all but the first and last dollar signs from each line".

Comment: @DaveCross Yeah, just reading the question again. Not 100% clear anymore -- the part at the start suggests that `10$x$10$x$10$x$10` becomes `$10x10x10x10$`, but the `Required Output` section suggests something else.

Comment: @pmqs: Thanks for your efforts and its working fine for the above said sample input. 
However I have updated the `input` and its doesn't working out. Could you please check in my question. (New Input)

Comment: You have moved the goalposts with new requirements! :-) In the new text I see that most of the digit-dollar texts are enclosed in a  `Sample paragraph testing ... text continues` block, but you have added a new one: `A 10$\times$10$\times$10 supercell was first built`. Can these digit-dollar sequences appear in arbitrary locations in the text, or is there a predefined set if prefixes that can be used to detect them (like the `ample paragraph testing` prefix)?

Comment: @pmqs: Thnq its working fine. +1